# Webcam en ventana modal

Tags: javascript, html5, laravel, modal, qrcode

Estoy desarrollando un sistema en laravel y estoy tratando de implementar un lector de código QR en un modal, el problema es que no me carga la webcam en el modal, estoy usando html5-qrcode.min.js para decodificar el qr y cargar la webcam, lo he probado en una pagina aparte y i código funciona, espero y me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Codigo HTML:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="webcam" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Leer QR</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div  class="center" id="reader" style="width:300px;height:250px;"></div>
        <textarea id="read" class=""></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#reader').html5_qrcode(function(data){
        $('#read').html(data);
      },
      function(error){
        $('#read_error').html(error);
      }, function(videoError){
        alert('No hay camara');
      }
      );
    });
```

Comment: si lo solucionas podrias subir tu codigo por fa esta interesante lo que vas hacer

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el error?